# Why is the Google Apps Script debugger incorrectly reporting the number of array items?

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script

maybe I'm doing it the wrong way, but I want to combine 2 arrays of different length in one object, so I use this code:

```
function MyArrayOfFilesAndFolders(){
   var folders = [my array of folders] // 60 items
   var files = [my array of files] // 220 items
   var res = {
              folders: folders,
              files: files
             }
   return res
}
```

The resulting object has 60 items for folders, but only 100 items for files (despite the fact that the original array "files" contains 220 items).

There's something wrong in this method or is a GAS bug?
I'm missing something else?

Thanks for any help

Comment: The debug mode now only shows the first 100 items of an array so if that's what you are judging the array length by, you may be mistaken. Try `Logger.log(res.files.length)` and report back.

Comment: @Jonathon Thanks, you' re right! The strange thing is that in the debugger I see the "files" array that has 220 items and only when I combine  with the other array (folders, 60 items) it goes to 100 items. Where did you read about this limit in the debugger?

Comment: It was a change made some time ago essentially for performance reasons. Handling super large arrays used to cause significant slow down, where it was browser DOM that was the limiting factor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Jonathon says, the debugger has a limit on the length of the arrays and in some cases it truncates long arrays to 100 items. 
To test the real length of an array, it's better to use Logger.log("number of items: " + array.length).

Comment: Actually I would like this 'new' feature of the debugger to include an array count as part of the UI. Limiting the rows to 100 is fine, but sometimes having the length reported as part of the debug property would be good.

Comment: @Jonathon The debugger does include this info. Click on the show all items button on the upper right of the toolbar when debugging.

Comment: @DouglasGaskell yes, I'm already using this for object directories when needed, but I'm lazy I want array count just there.  It is there, but a truncated array shows 100. I'd like this to be the actual count.

Comment: @Jonathon It gives you the count. It still cuts off the array view at 100 (Which is insanely annoying) but there is a `length` variable that's now visible for arrays.

Comment: I should pay more attention. On the other hand I have accidentally expanded a 10000 item array in the debugger and waited half a week just for the browser to process, so the truncation makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you want it to display the values... Does this help?:

```
   function MyArrayOfFilesAndFolders(){
   var folders = ["I", "Am", "Robot"];
   var files = ["Yes","In","Deed"] 
   var res = folders+files;
   Logger.log(res)
}
```

If it doesn't can you be more specific?
Cheers!

Comment: Thanks but it's not the point of my question; i try to explain it better:
i have two arrays of different length and i want to combine in one object; the resulting object is something like:
'{ [files]
    [value]
    [value]
  [folders]
    [value]
    [value]
    [value]
    [value]
    [value]
 } '
and it's fine for my purposes.
The real problem is that, in my case, any array greater than 100 items is truncated when I combine it with another array using the function i've posted in my question... so I'm asking if I'm doing it wrong or is a bug in Google Apps Script.

Comment: @ManuelSerrenti how are you determining that your array has been truncated? There should be no reason for that to happen. Also try Jonathons suggestion, log the array length, debug will only show the first 100 items.